# C# application where to find data source/database tables used in a program with search

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, data-access

I have inherited a C# application that somehow saves/saved data sometime ago. I am fairly new to Visual Studio IDE and C# in general, and I have been given the task of finding where in our database this program saves data to. Any idea on how to proceed as I don't seem to be able to find out how this program interacts and saves data to my database?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you set breakpoints and run the application and walk through the code using the Visual Studio debugger.

There are a lot of resources covering debugging in Visual Studio. You might start with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If i know what DB tables to search for, is there anyway to do a thorough search of the entire project for a table e.g. KX_SUPPORT, since somewhere in the application, it should be referencing a table that it wants to save data to depending on the input from the user.